# How do I add connection string to stimulsoft report build in .net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, stimulsoft

I want to use Stimulsoft report viewer to load reports using angular and .net core (.net5 actually).
I am having a hard time adding SQL connection string to the report.
I have followed their official [documentation](https://www.stimulsoft.com/en/documentation/online/programming-manual/index.html?reports_web_asp_net_core_using_web_viewer_connecting_data.htm) on how to do this but it doesn't work.
What happens when I use this is that `((StiSqlDatabase)report.Dictionary.Databases` throws a null reference exception.

This is how my code looks like

The other way I try to do this is `report.Dictionary.Databases.Add(new StiSqlDatabase("ArchBD", "DataBaseConnectionString"));`
This throws an exception with the message `Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0`.

My connection string is like this: `"Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb; Database=MyDB; Trusted_Connection=True;"`

I have used this format too: `"Data Source=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Initial Catalog=MyDB;Integrated Security=True;"`

This one throws `A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to sql`

```
var report = new StiReport();
var path = StiAngularHelper.MapPath(this, $"{report}.mrt");
report.Load(path);
var ConnectionString = ConnectionString;
var conn = new Stimulsoft.Report.Dictionary.StiSqlDatabase("MyDb", ConnectionString);
report.Dictionary.Databases.Add(conn);
```

Guys please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve it by looking at the report file and picked the right name for the connection name

```xml
<Dictionary Ref="1" type="Dictionary" isKey="true">
    <Databases isList="true" count="1">
      <ConnectionName Ref="2" type="Stimulsoft.Report.Dictionary.StiSqlDatabase" isKey="true">
        <Alias>ConnectionName </Alias>
```

then used

```cs
((StiSqlDatabase)report.Dictionary.Databases["ConnectionName"]).ConnectionString = @"Data Source=server;Integrated Security=True;Initial Catalog=MyDB";
```